# What is equvalent code for following c# code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml, vb.net

```
if (node.Attributes != null)   //checking for attributes of a xml file node.
```

Comment: That isn't even valid C# for a start. There is no such operator as `<>`.

Comment: in C# there is no <> operator, != is the correct case

Comment: sorry its: if(node.Attributes != null)

Comment: -1: Not a real question: equivalent code in what language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Not (node.Attributes Is Nothing) Then

Comment: is this If node.Attributes Is Not Nothing Then return something different ?

Comment: I prefer IsNot Nothing which is more intuitive than Not ... Is Nothing, but it does work.

Comment: ..though as noted by Chris Haas, in VS2003, it's the only alternative.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are looking for the equivelant in VB.NET:

```
If node.Attributes Is Not Nothing Then
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be IsNot Nothing?

Comment: With VB2005 we got the "IsNot" keyword. Previously we had to use the more awkward syntax of "If Not obj Is Nothing Then"

Answer (score 2):

```
if (node.Attributes != null)
```

**Edit:**

you have edit your question 
VB.Net Equilent code..

```
If node.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then
```

Comment: He _did_ tag it with VB.NET... should have been a clue :)

Comment: It's not the right syntax... Nicky Waites has posted the right syntax (IsNot)

Answer (score 1):

I find [charp-to-vb](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) a great site for converting between c# and vb.net

In this case

```
If node.Attributes IsNot Nothing Then
End If
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think there is an error?  If it is the End If then fair enough since you wont need that with a single statement.